# Linear Algebra/Operator theory nomenclature or reference request

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request, operator-theory

Given positive semidefinite operators $P,Q≥0$, is there a name for the operator $$S:=P^{1/2}Π₊(P^{1/2}QP^{1/2})P^{1/2},$$ where $$Π₊(P^{1/2}QP^{1/2})=\text {the projection onto the range of } P^{1/2}QP^{1/2} \text{ ?}$$  Any reference or known terminology would be helpful, because I'm writing up a paper that uses this extensively, but I don't know if there is a standard name for it.